# Verilog 4-bit carry select adder

Tags: if-statement, verilog

So I am trying to design a 4-bit carry select adder in verilog, and am using the following code for the design:

```
module fullAdder (S,Cout,P,G,A,B,Cin);
// Define all inputs and outputs for single bit Fulll Adder
    output S;
    output Cout;
    output P;
    output G;
    input A;
    input B;
    input Cin;

// Full Adder body, define structure and internal wiring
    wire t1, t2, t3;

    xor xor1 (t1, A, B);
    xor xor2 (S, t1, Cin);

    or or1 (P, A, B);
    and and1 (G, A, B);
    and and2 (t2, P, Cin);
    or or2 (Cout, t2, G);

endmodule 

module carrySelect (sum, cout, a, b, cin);
  output [3:0] sum;    //sum output of the adder, 4 bits wide
  output cout;           //carry out of the adder
  input [3:0] a;          //input a, 4 bits wide
  input [3:0] b;         //input b, 4 bits wide
  input cin;              //carry in of the adder

  reg ch, cl;   //temporary variables to define cases that previous carry is high or low
  wire [3:0] C;     //carry bus
  wire [3:0] P,G;   //buses for P and G outputs of fullAdder
  wire [1:0] s0, s1, s2, s3;    //temporary buses for cases of sums
  wire [1:0] c0, c1, c2, c3;    //temporary buses for cases of carries

  assign ch = 1;    //assign ch to high and cl to low
  assign cl = 0;

  //least significant full adder computation
  fullAdder f0_h (s0[0],c0[0],p0[0], g0[0], a[0], b[0], ch); 
  fullAdder f0_l (s0[1],c0[1],p0[1], g0[1], a[0], b[0], cl);

  fullAdder f1_h (s1[0],c1[0],p1[0], g1[0], a[0], b[0], ch);
  fullAdder f1_l(s1[1],c1[1],p1[1], g1[1], a[0], b[0], cl);

  fullAdder f2_h (s2[0],c2[0],p2[0], g2[0], a[0], b[0], ch);
  fullAdder f2_l (s2[1],c2[1],p2[1], g2[1], a[0], b[0], cl);

  //most significant full adder computation
  fullAdder f3_h (s3[0],c3[0],p3[0], g3[0], a[0], b[0], ch);
  fullAdder f3_l (s3[1],c3[1],p3[1], g3[1], a[0], b[0], cl);

  //select output depending on values of carries

  if (cin == 1) begin
    assign sum[0] = s0[0];
    assign C[0] = c0[0];
  end else begin
    assign sum[0] = s0[1];  
    assign C[0] = c0[1];
  end

  if(C[0] == 1) begin
    assign sum[1] = s1[0];
    assign C[1] = c1[0];
  end else begin
    assign sum[1] = s1[1];  
    assign C[1] = c1[1];
  end

  if(C[1]) begin
    assign sum[2] = s2[0];
    assign C[2] = c2[0];
  end else begin
    assign sum[2] = s2[1];  
    assign C[2] = c2[1];
  end

  if(C[2]) begin
    assign sum[3] = s3[0];
    assign C[3] = c3[0];
  end else begin
    assign sum[3] = s3[1];  
    assign C[3] = c3[1];
  end

  //assign carry out
  assign cout = C[3];

endmodule
```

where the full adder is completely functional, so there are no problems there. I get errors from the if statements when I try to compile the code, and get the warning about implicit definitions and error of not being able to evaluate genvar of the conditional in the ifs. I am fairly new to verilog, so I apologize if this is a trivial fix. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT1:Error/warning message thrown

```
design.sv:57: warning: implicit definition of wire fullAdderTest.UUT.cin.
design.sv:57: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: (cin)==('sd1)
design.sv:57: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: (cin)==('sd1)
design.sv:65: warning: implicit definition of wire fullAdderTest.UUT.C.
design.sv:65: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: (C['sd0])==('sd1)
design.sv:65: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: (C['sd0])==('sd1)
design.sv:73: warning: Constant bit select [1] is after vector C[0:0].
design.sv:73:        : Replacing select with a constant 1'bx.
design.sv:73: warning: Constant bit select [1] is after vector C[0:0].
design.sv:73:        : Replacing select with a constant 1'bx.
design.sv:81: warning: Constant bit select [2] is after vector C[0:0].
design.sv:81:        : Replacing select with a constant 1'bx.
design.sv:81: warning: Constant bit select [2] is after vector C[0:0].
design.sv:81:        : Replacing select with a constant 1'bx.
4 error(s) during elaboration.
```

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement outside of an `always` or `initial` block is treated as a if it was inside an `generate` block. A generate's if statement will accepts literal constants (hard coded values), parameters, and genvars. It will not accept net or register types (i.e: `wire`, `reg`, `integer`, etc). Generate blocks are evaluated during elaboration and therefore cannot depend on simulation variables with dynamic values.

You want conditionally select the values for `sum` and `C` based on input values. There are a few options to do this:

One option is to make an inline condition statement:

```
assign sum[0] = cin ? s0[0] : s0[1];
assign C[0]   = cin ? c0[0] : c0[1];
// ...
```

Or you can select the index (same effect):

```
assign sum[0] = s0[!cin];
assign C[0]   = c0[!cin];
assign sum[1] = s1[!C[0]];
assign C[1]   = c1[!C[0]];
// ...
```

Or make `sum` and `C` `reg` types and put all the if statements inside an always block (remove the `assign`s):

```
always @* begin
  if (cin == 1) begin
    sum[0] = s0[0];
    C[0] = c0[0];
  end
  else begin
    sum[0] = s0[1];  
    C[0] = c0[1];
  end
  // ...
end
```